# How to get all the datetime values coming from debezium to yyyy-mm-dd-ss.zzz format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, debezium, change-data-capture

I would like know how to get all DATETIME(io.debezium.time.Timestamp) coming from Debezium sql server connector in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format. Right now this is giving in epoch int64 format which will be difficult to transform data using spark.

configuration for debezium sql server connector used below:

```
{
    "name": "localDB-sqlserverconnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "database.hostname": "192.168.1.22",
        "database.port": "1433",
        "database.user": "user",
        "database.password": "user_123",
        "database.dbname": "localDB",
        "database.server.name": "DEV1",
        "table.whitelist": "dbo.testtabledebezium",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.1.81:32105",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "history_DB.DEV1",
        "include.schema.changes": false,
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": true,
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only"
        
    }
}
```

result from debezium for topic DEV1.dbo.testtabledebezium

```
{"id":9,"column1":"t6","column2":1601480866593,"column3":18535,"__deleted":"false"}
```

Sqlserver table actual data

```
|id|    |column1|   |column2                |   |column3   | =>
|9 |    |t6     |   |2020-09-30 15:47:46.593|   |2020-09-30|
```

Actual requirement

```
{"id":9,"column1":"t6","column2":"2020-09-30 15:47:46.593","column3":"2020-09-30","__deleted":"false"}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below to your debezium connector configuration

```
{
    "transforms":"unwrap,col2",  
    "transforms.col2.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.col2.target.type":"string", 
    "transforms.col2.field":"col2", 
    "transforms.col2.format":"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" ,
    "time.precision.mode":"connect"
}
```

Add it for col3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add "time.precision.mode": "connect" to your connector config.

Refer https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-temporal-values